# How can I make these data types display their values on screen?

Tags: java, swing, japplet

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JApplet{
byte january = 1;

int date = 18;

long year = 1995;
```

I want the screen to be able to say: 1/18/1995 and I'm not sure of how to accomplish that.

Comment: See [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Comment: Do yourself a favour, stay away from applets until you have a better understand of the API, start with something like [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) and [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more basic details

Comment: I have to make this display in an applet.

Comment: *"I have to make this display in an applet."* **Why** an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Use the built in `println()` method:</strike>

```
System.out.println(month + "//" + date + "//" + year);
```

**EDIT** for use with `JApplet` (Swing)

Put this in a label:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;

// ... other code

JLabel label = new JLabel(month + "//" + date + "//" + year);
// you can set the vertical and horizontal text positions with these lines: 
// label1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
// label1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);

// assuming your JPanel is called panel
panel.add(label);
```

(the double backslahes are to escape each other and print out a single backslash; you use `+` operator to concatenate strings; month, date, and year will automatically be converted to strings here)

Comment: `... extends JApplet {...` - So I guess it's not going to be as helpful as you think

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't see that. I'll upload a Swing equivalent

Comment: The output says I need a return type added to add(label); portion.

Comment: If you have a JPanel called `panel`, try `panel.add(label);`. I updated my answer.

Comment: I don't have a panel in my code

Comment: @NotAnything123 Do you have a frame? What is the basis for your Swing application GUI? What do you want to put the text on?

Comment: I just want the out put to say 1/18/1995. Here's a pic of what it looks like: https://gyazo.com/4207d5a10c1b1b00d3bdd3d2815fe978

Comment: @NotAnything123 You're going to have to know more about Swing then. See [this example usage of JLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) (unless you just want to print something to the console: if so, then just look at my original crossed-out answer)